# Why is there a several second lag for my external monitor to turn on when waking up my MacBook M1?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

It's a Deco Gear DGVM27AB connected through the DisplayPort if that helps.

Comment: It's normal. Every external monitor I've ever used, connected to any number of Mac laptops for the past 15 years, always has a lag when the machine comes out of sleep.

Comment: see [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/811712)

Comment: I have 2 identical external displays, one on DVI the other on DP. The DVI is several seconds slower than the DP, whichever way round I connect them. Go figure ;)